# RSS Feed not producing accurate results after tag renaming

Tags: bug, tag-synonym-process

Before requesting that the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag be renamed to [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud), I posted a series of questions about the renaming process here: [Questions regarding the tag merging/synonym impact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303772/questions-regarding-the-tag-merging-synonym-impact)

Now that the tag has been changed, I have noticed that RSS feeds are not accurate. If you have an existing feed that is looking for the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tagged content, it DOES NOT include any new content that was not originally tagged as [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix).

For example:

- From before the rename, if you created content that was tagged [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) and renamed [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) by the back-end process, that content **IS** included in the RSS feed looking for content tagged with [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix).
- If you create new content using the [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) tag, it **IS NOT** included in any original RSS feeds looking for the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag.

The RSS feed apparently does not adjust and look for the parent tag when [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) is a synonym.

This issue is a HUGE problem as all original RSS feeds looking for [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tagged content will need to be updated to look for [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud). We have teams that follow the RSS feeds to see when people ask questions about their area of focus.

You can see the difference here:

- [ibm-cloud] tagged content RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=ibm-cloud&sort=newest
- [ibm-bluemix] tagged content RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=ibm-bluemix&sort=newest
  New attempts to follow this RSS feed result in a "not found" error message when trying to add it as a Live Feed Bookmark to FireFox. An existing RSS feed is missing the latest [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud)entries from the last few days after the rename/synonym change.

This issue seems to be a bug in how the RSS feeds work. Can someone investigate and hopefully fix it?

Comment: Ahh... so what animuson said about transparent remapping doesn't appear to work then?

Comment: @JonClements Apparently not. The Advanced API for pulling tag metrics, for example, works if you substitute [ibm-cloud] for [ibm-bluemix]. But, the RSS feeds do not.

Comment: I wonder if it's something I did wrongly - I'm only a community moderator, not staff, but everything I did went through without errors and told me all the re-mappings had completed... etc... so yeah, thinking it's likely something's not happening on the backend, I'm fairly sure I created all the syns correctly.

Comment: @JonClements I am not blaming you and thank you very much for the help. :-) I think it is a SO bug with the RSS feeds.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, so apparently the synonym thing only *half* works for RSS feeds.

**The problem:** The RSS feed currently only redirects to its master tag version if there is still at least one question tagged with the synonym tag still in the system. When tags gets merged, all the tags get changed and that is no longer true. However, the RSS feed really *should* still redirect even if the synonym tag has no questions left. That's something we need to fix in the system at some point.

**Temporary workaround:** I created the [ibm-bluemix-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix-test) tag on the oldest question, then merged it into [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) so there is at least one question still with the old tag. The RSS feed now works as it should. Hopefully no one will edit that question until the bug gets fixed so your feed will continue working.

Comment: Thank you for the temporary workaround. At the moment, it looks like Firefox Live Bookmarks is picking up the RSS Feed correctly, but Feedly is showing the same symptoms with just 4 posts from the last couple of days. I'll give it 24 hours to hopefully clear up. In terms of a permanent workaround, should I log the issue elsewhere to help?

Comment: @William This is the appropriate place for bug reports. Someone will get to it. :) That's weird that you somehow got 4 questions, though. I can't imagine what might've caused that.